# Why are Knuth, CLRS hash functions not sufficient

Tags: hash

It's easy to prove that, given some set of keys with an unknown distribution, we can't construct a function who, taking these keys as input, outputs values which are uniformly distributed.

As such, we look at general-purpose hash functions, for unknown distributions.

Knuth recommends exploiting non-repeating digits of irrational numbers - most notably the golden ratio - in order to distribute the keys evenly over table range.

CLRS recommends simply taking the keys mod a large prime, again, to roughly distribute keys evenly over table range, and to break down repeating patterns.

In both cases, the objective seems to be to evenly distribute the keys.

But, when looking at solutions like Murmur2, SeaHash, ect - they seem to place quite a lot of effort on ensuring a "butterfly-like" effect: given a key, changing any 1 bit has good chance to change every bit in the hash.

Why is this behaviour desirable? What are the shortcomings of those solutions presented in TAOCP and CLRS?

If the desired behavior is to break-down any patterns in the set of input keys, then the implicit assumption here is that sets of keys exhibiting *any* sort of pattern are more likely in the wild? Is this reasonable?

Sorry if I am not being precise.

Edit: Does not need to be of cryptographic strength. Purpose is to minimize collisions.

Comment: This question might be better asked over at https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: It depends on the purpose you are using the hash function. If you want to hide the original info (e.g. passwords), then it is desirable that one cannot make conclusions about the original info, by observing similarities of two hashes.

Comment: @martinstoeckli See edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure about this, but this may be an artifact of the different assumptions made by the different authors in different contexts.

Knuth’s work in TAoCP was done way before any of these other books or hash functions were developed. At the time, Knuth was in a sense trailblazing how to analyze and think about different algorithms and data structures. At the time, the idea of “use some scheme to distribute things into buckets” was known, but no one had seriously thought through how best to choose that scheme. His approaches are mathematically simple and elegant and ran quickly on contemporary (1970s) hardware. The general theme was “if you’re going to distribute according to some function, here’s a really nice and simple one to use and a good theory behind it.”

Knuth’s first paper analyzing data structures or algorithms, IIRC, was on hash tables. He did that analysis on the assumption that the hash codes were uniformly random and showed that under those assumptions the hash table performs well.

As you mentioned, though, it’s clear that if you pick any fixed hash function you will have degenerate input cases. A bunch of people started thinking about how to handle this, and many folks experimented with the idea of choosing a hash function randomly from a pool of available hash functions. In the late 1970s Wegman published a paper entitled [Universal Classes of Hash Functions](https://www.arl.wustl.edu/~sailesh/download_files/Limited_Edition/hash/Universal%20classes%20of%20hash%20functions%20(Extended%20Abstract).pdf) that outlined a formal mathematical definition of what it would mean for a family of hash functions to be a good class of hash functions to pick from. This paper included a proof that universal families of hash functions have low expected numbers of collisions, making them great for chained hash tables.

The first edition of CLRS was published in 1990 and incorporates both Knuth’s analysis of linear probing (assuming truly random hash codes) and an analysis of chained hash tables using universal hashing. In other words, it acknowledges that you have to be careful when picking hash functions (no one fixed function will always work, so look at universal hashing) but also does some math under the assumption that you have a “sufficiently good” hash function.

(Later theoretical developments include the landmark paper “Why Simple Hash Functions Work,” explaining why weak hash functions combined with a tiny amount of entropy in the input distribution essentially act like truly random functions, and some later work showing that 5-independent hash functions are all you need to get very good performance in linear probing tables.)

All of the above work lives in Theoryland, where the goal is to build up nice mathematical frameworks for analyzing data structures and to make concrete recommendations for approaches in practice to get good distributions and efficiency.

Then there’s The Real World, where practitioners don’t always get the math and the math often lags behind what the practitioners are doing.

If you look at most work on hash functions, many hash functions assume that you’re working with data that can easily be decomposed into integer units in a meaningful way. But real data doesn’t always decompose nicely that way. Or perhaps you have a language like C++, Java, Python, etc. where every object has “a” hash code that’s *the* hash code associated with it, rather than what the theory folks recommend of having families of available hash functions.

In situations like these, it’s not all that unreasonable to try to build a hash function that is (1) crazy fast to evaluate, (2) can work across different runs of the same program or multiple machines, and (3) works “well enough” in practice that people don’t complain. That’s where you get hash functions like MurmurHash and the like - they fill this need really, really well. Assuming that you aren’t working against adversarially-chosen inputs, these sorts of hash functions are fine.

What’s interesting is that we’re now seeing a resurgence of Knuth’s
multiplicative hash functions. Libraries that let you combine different hash functions together, like Boost’s `hash_combine`, use that technique to give a deterministic yet well-spread hash code given multiple existing hashes as input.

To summarize:

- A lot of these differences are historical. Knuth built out a theoretical foundation for how to analyze hash functions and considered the case where you have a single hash function. Later work on universal hashing gave a different perspective and framework for working with classes of hash functions.
- There’s always a gap between theory and practice. For non-adversarial situations, non-randomized hashes like MurmurHash are simple, fast, and work well. They also work well with variable-length inputs, compared to single integer values.

Comment: This is a thorough answer. Perhaps the sentence that sums things up best: "Then there’s The Real World, where practitioners don’t always get the math and the math often lags behind what the practitioners are doing". Also, thank you very much for referring me to the paper "Why Simple Hash Functions Work".